# C# get applications internet ussage

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like write application, in Visul Studio C#, that allow users to set bandwith limit of internet.

I can get all working applications from

```
    Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
```

But is there a way to get internet usage and set bandwith limit for application?